# Table or database name may not contain dot(.) character

Tags: hive

When I use hive to create a table, I am prompted not to include the dot symbol.
(state=42000,code=40000)

How can I solve this problem?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `ods.a2`(
  `key` string COMMENT 'k', 
  `value` string COMMENT 'v')
COMMENT '注释'
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'field.delim'=',,', 
  'serialization.format'=',,') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
'hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/ods.db/a2';
```

err:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:22 Table or database name may not contain dot(.) character 'ods.a2' (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Comment: HDP - Hive-3.1.0

Comment: i dont think you can :). Curious, why you need a dot in table name? dot normally used to denote database name in everywhere in sql world. however there is a way to include dot in column name in hive.

Comment: Thank you for your reply，The main reason is that I want to add tags to the database，ods is a database name.  I changed it to CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `ods`.`a2`....

Comment: You can comment on table as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `ods`.`a2`

If any components of a multiple-part name require quoting, quote them individually rather than quoting the name as a whole. For example, write `my-table`.`my-column`, not `my-table.my-column`